# ROS programming with C++

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!
I am learning ROS programming. I want to know is there any book or course which explains **"ROS programming using C++ language"**? not only ROS environment specifically but also implementation of C++ in ROS. If someone knows, please recommend me. Suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290609/ros-programming-with-c++/) by [Ibrahim_aerospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/34015/ibrahim_aerospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2018-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here you find the books
http://wiki.ros.org/Books
Greet

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2018-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would also add that if you don't have any c/c++ programming experience I would advise you to learn the basics outside of ROS. It is not the gentlest introduction to c++!

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-08**:
+100 to this. I would actually say that it's not an introduction *at all*, and should not be used that way. (Extensive) knowledge of and experience with C++ is expected, especially if you want / have to work on some of the more internal parts of `roscpp`.